# Каким API запросом можно изменить DNS records у домена на gandi.net?

Tags: dns

Не могу разобраться с документацией на офф сайте, 
Мож кто работает с ним уже.

У меня есть Логин, Пароль аккаунта Gandi.net, Купленный домен PW.
Хочу через API изменить его DNS records

например на:

```
@ 10800 IN SOA ns1.gandi.net. hostmaster.gandi.net. 1524454574 10800 3600 604800 10800
* 1800 IN A 94.172.19.100
@ 1800 IN A 94.172.19.100
```

Comment: gandi.net домен PW

Comment: В поддержку уже обращались?

Comment: Да, чет сомневаюсь, что ответят